# Output list and numpy array into same file

Tags: python, numpy

I have the foll. list:

```
ll = ['ncols         4320\n', 'nrows         2160\n', 'xllcorner     -180\n', 'yllcorner     -90\n', 'cellsize      0.083333001\n', 'NODATA_value  -9999\n']
```

and a numpy 2d array:

```
arr = [[1.0,2.0],[3.0,4.0]]
```

I want to create a new text file and first output the list into it (one element per line) and then output the 2D array (one row per line). Right now, I can output the array as such:

```
numpy.savetxt('out.txt', delimiter=' ')
```

How do I append the list into this output file?

Comment: You can open the file yourself, write to it, and then pass it to `savetxt`.  `savetxt` is equally happy with a filename or an already opened file.

Comment: thanks @hpaulj, if you can write this as answer, i will be happy to accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open the file yourself, write to it, and then pass it to `savetxt`. `savetxt` is equally happy with a filename or an already opened file.

I just demonstrated that in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33512035/901925

```
In [26]: with open('test.txt','w') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, data.T, delimiter=',', fmt='%12s')
    np.savetxt(f, data.T, delimiter=';', fmt='%10s') # simulate a 2nd array
```