# Passing Multidimensional Numpy arrays through a function and saving results in a CSV file

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I have a multidimensional Numpy array with ‘n’ rows and 3 columns.

I want to call first ‘m’ rows as a sub array and pass it through a function and the resulting array (with no. of rows = m) from the function will be saved in a csv file “solution.csv”.

Then second set of ‘m’ rows should be passed through the same function and resulting array (with no. of rows = m) should be added to “solution.csv”.

In the end “solution.csv” will have ‘n’ rows resulting from consecutive addition of all m rows from the result generated by the function.

I am finding trouble in writing an appropriate code in python as I am a novice.

Answer (score 2):

A sample that does this:

The array:

```
In [19]: A=np.arange(30).reshape(10,3)
```

A function:

```
In [20]: def foo(Asub, x):
    return Asub+x
```

Pass 2 parts through the function, rejoin them (with `vstack`):

```
In [21]: B=np.vstack([foo(A[:5,:],3),foo(A[5:,:],4)])
In [22]: B
Out[22]: 
array([[ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
          ...
       [28, 29, 30],
       [31, 32, 33]])
```

and write the csv in one call:

```
In [23]: np.savetxt('test.csv',B,fmt='%10d')
In [24]: cat test.csv
         3          4          5
         6          7          8
         9         10         11
        12         13         14
        15         16         17
        19         20         21
        22         23         24
        25         26         27
        28         29         30
        31         32         33
```

This is straight forward use of array indexing (slicing), concatenation, and csv writing.

`savetxt` can also be called with an open file (the docs say `file handle`) , so I can use `foo` and `savetxt` in 2 steps:

```
with open('text.csv','bw') as f:
    a1 = foo(A[:5,:],3)
    np.savetxt(f,a1,fmt='%10d')
    a2 = foo(A[5:,:],5)
    np.savetxt(f,a2,fmt='%10d')
```

Or I could reopen the file the second time in append mode.

I gave a similar answer to a question about saving a 3d array - as multiple 2d blocks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33705223/901925

and [Output list and numpy array into same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529207/output-list-and-numpy-array-into-same-file)

Comment: Thanks. What about using loops (in In [21]:) to call sub arrays to pass through the function? I think that would be better.

Comment: Sure a loop would be natural if you need to work with more slices.